# Simplifying validation for different id's in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I want this code of validation to be simplified.

```
if($('#textbox1').val() != '' && $('#textbox2').val() != '' && $('#textbox3').val() != ''){
   $('#myModal').modal('show');
}else {
   alert ('textboxes must be empty');
}
```

I already put `required` attribute to each `textbox` but I want another validation before showing the modal. Are other way to simplify this? I have tried it this way,

```
if($('#textbox1, #textbox2, #textbox3'){
   $('#myModal').modal('show');
}else {
   alert ('textboxes must be empty');
}
```

but it only recognizes the first id (`textbox1`). If the other `textboxes` are empty it will still display the modal.

Answer (score 2):

You can just select by class and filter

```
if ($("[required]").filter(function() { return !this.value.length; }).length) { 
    //stuff is not filled in
} else {
   //filled in
}
```

or you can just use any of the validation libraries for jQuery.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" required />
<input type="text" required />
<input type="text" required />
```

JavaScript:

```
$("[required]").on("change", function() {
    var color;
    if ($("[required]").filter(function() { return !this.value.length; }).length) { 
        color = "red";
    } else {
       color = "green";
    }
    $("body").css("background-color", color);
}).eq(0).trigger("change");
```

Comment: oops.. it's not working when the statement is `false` it only works when it's `true`.. maybe a glitch or what?

Comment: or shall I say it's not returning a `false` statement only true because it's not doing the codes inside `else`.

Comment: What do you think is wrong? It returns all the elements with no value set. If there is 1 or more elements, it will be true. If no elements are returned [all filled in] it will be false since zero is a false value. The order is different than your if/else above.

Comment: I use this code of yours,
`if ($(".required").filter(function() { return !this.value.length; }).length) { 
    //stuff is not filled in
} else {
   alert ('textboxes must be empty');
}` the alert message is not showing when the fields have values.

Comment: Did you change it to "[required]" since you used an attribute and not a class?

Comment: I would make a fiddle, but it is down right now. The code should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="textbox1" value="0"/>
<input type="text" id="textbox2" value="2"/>
<input type="text" id="textbox3" value="  "/>

jquery

var array = $("input[id^=textbox]").filter(function (index, element) {
    return element.value.trim().length != 0;
});

if (array.length === 3) {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
} else {
    alert('textboxes must be empty');
}
```